# Переведите из C# в C++

Tags: c#, c++

```
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Some Title";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Some Notification";
        notifyIcon1.Text = "Application Name";
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. С чем конкретно у вас проблема? Что вызывает сложности?

Answer (score 2):

```
notifyIcon1->balloonTipTitle = "Some Title";
notifyIcon1->balloonTipText = "Some Notification";
notifyIcon1->text = "Application Name";
```

Пожалуйста (=

Comment: ;0) 15 символов